# Can Kentico's script and css minification be disabled for a dev environment?

Tags: javascript, css, kentico

I'm writing some JS for analytic event tracking. Part of my function is a e.preventdefault(). This is temporary thing, but when i view the compressed JS, this has been changed to n.preventdefault() which gives an error. So, is there a way to have the raw JS (and css) for dev, without adjusted to JS call?

Answer (score 3):

Within Settings > System > Performance, you can enable or disable JavaScript and CSS minification. I'm assuming these are enabled by default which serves my purpose.